# The meaning of 废柴码农

Tags: meaning, phrase

Someone called me a 废柴码农 after I made a silly mistake.  I suppose it must be something negative but what does it actually means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

废柴码农 means something like incompetent programmer. Usually 废柴 is used as a noun, for example, many fans of Man United say Darren Fletcher is 废柴. 码农 is a self-deprecating name for programmers, and its original meaning in Chinese is coding peasant.

Comment: Thanks Zeno.  Now it makes sense.  Just wondering how bad it is?  (It's from my colleague by the way)

Comment: @user3919509 How bad is 废柴 depends on the context. Generally I feel it's very similar to 'idiot' in English. 码农 is not too negative or not at all.

Comment: @user3919509 It depends more on the tone rather than the words. "you are so smart" can be extremely negative, right?

Comment: haha, usually we don't say 废柴 to strangers, mostly say that for self-mockery or talking in close friends. BTW, 码农 is also a self-mockery word. People usually say that in a relaxed context, rather than serious. So don't feel bad about that.

Answer (score 3):

It's an informal, mocking expression used only on the internet. Don't take it seriously or use it in real life.

Comment: I must have done something REALLY bad, but my colleague is an xxxxxxx calling me that

Comment: not that serious. sometimes people just use 废柴 to make fun of others.

Answer (score 3):

廢柴碼農 means useless coding farmer.

碼農 is a word used in Mainland China. In Mainland China, farmers (農) are lower class and not supposed to be respected.  Describe a programmer as farmer is not respect to your job.

廢柴 is a borrow word from Cantonese. It is to describe a person useless.

Answer (score 2):

From baidu:
废柴，起源于粤语，多为骂人的词，随着《废柴兄弟》播出，废柴被衍生为坚持梦想的有（mei）为（qian）青（de）年（ren），其中在剧中的一对废柴许之一和张晓蛟被成为“柴帝”。“废柴”是一种社会现象，表面上看着很废，其实很有才，总有被燃烧的一天。废柴是一个自嘲式的正能量词语，多用于网友的自嘲，预示具有强大潜力。

码农Coding Peasant(s)：一般指从事没有发展前景的软件开发职位，这种职位只能强化职业者在单方面的技术领域技能，学不到新技术，同时也是部分从事软件开发工作人员的一个自嘲的称号。

Answer (score 1):

Wong,

廢柴 usually used to describe someone who is a "rubbish", a weak person.

This word is very common in Hong Kong,
it is not a foul language, but not polite